# subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector with argv

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, terminal, argc

I have this code.c in ubuntu in terminal 
but when I compile it with gcc this error appeared

```
cod2.c: In function ‘main’:
cod2.c:9:11: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
```

why is that?

```
int  main(int argc , char ** argv){
    mkdir(argc[1] , 00755);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got confused between `argc` (an int representing the number of arguments) and `argv` (an array of strings containing the command line arguments). Change:

```
mkdir(argc[1], 00755);
```

to:

```
mkdir(argv[1], 0755);
      ^^^^^^^
```

(Note that I also removed a redundant `0` prefix from `00755` to make it `0755` - you only need a single `0` prefix to signify octal base.)

For a real program you should also check that an argument has been provided, otherwise you will crash when the user does not supply an argument:

```
if (argc > 1)
{
    mkdir(argv[1], 0755);
}
```

Comment: nothing has changed!
yes argc was false but 00755 was true :)

Comment: Did you change `argc` to `argv`, save and re-compile ?

Comment: yes you are right :) argv is correct but 0 doesn't have problem

Comment: You mean the change from `00755` to `0755` ? I just fixed that because the extra `0` is redundant - you only need one `0` prefix to signify octal base.

Answer (score 0):

```
 mkdir(argv[1] , 00755);//try argv instead of argc
```

Your command line arguments are stored in `argv` only, not in `argc`. `argc` contains no of arguments in command lines. So try with `argv`